# Weird Circumstances after being Staffed

Tags: new-job, new-hires

I have been waiting to be staffed for more than two months.

I was happy when someone announced to me that I was going to be staffed with verbal details.

Naturally, I was expecting an official email with formal contact information about my new field boss, but nothing.

All I got was a phone number retrieved by a local manager from Whatsapp, and I was told to go to a specific office and call that manager who will then get me in, and then I could start my new mission.

When I called the new manager, he didn't anticipate, I told him my name, but it felt he didn't know what I wanted from him or something.

I had to explain to him the whole situation, that's when he told me to wait for him at the lobby ...

Later, he showed me my desk, and I kept waiting for something to happen, then he sent me some documents to read, some quick project introductions.

After that, he showed the first environment I was going to use on the computer.

I didn't do much on the first week (last week of September).

Indeed, I was expecting to be introduced to the team, at least the people I would be involved with directly, but nothing of that.

Last monday, he came to me and briefly told me to look at a second environment.

I spent a couple of days just reviewing, but that was a boring unclear task.

So I asked for more visibility and he told that I came in a busy period with a lot of incidents and that he doesn't have time for me. Plus, he doesn't have an interesting subject yet to assign to me. Interesting as easy and useful.

A new week has started and I still seem invisible to him.

He doesn't need me, maybe, and he wishes I leave?

Aren't there welcoming rituals for new team members?

Or is this such a mundane situation?

Comment: Could you please tell us where you are and what you do as an occupation?

Comment: You fret a lot about your job  - i could not get a clear picture about your situation from your other questions - could you include a clear timeline? ---

Answer (score 4):

I think that when your manager tells you that the timing is bad and that he's busy, he's telling the truth. That doesn't mean that he doesn't want you there, he just doesn't have the time to hold your hand.

Agreeing with Strader's answer, I think you, yourself, should try and be more active. You should have been in the first place. In case the manager doesn't automatically introduce you to his team, you can ask him to do that yourself or if he's too busy, ask someone else from the team to do it instead.

It's quite common to have "a slow start" when it comes to work. They might not have planned your tasks yet or there might be a lack of projects at that current moment. If your manager doesn't assign tasks for you, you can ask around from your team if there's anything you could do to help or try to get more comfortable with the softwares you're using.

This is just the beginning, you'll just need to do what you can do at the moment and don't assume that everything is handed to you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should be a bit proactive

Being employed in the Middle East / Northern Africa region myself few times in the past,

in my experience, lots of places are in chaos from time to time.

Looks like you did came at the bad time, but nothing to it, if you want to make it a workplace you love.

Few things you can do that helped me at the time:

1. Ask for access to repository branch that is not going in to production and any documentation your manager have on the subject.
2. Analyze it and familiarize yourself with the product, maybe read open tickets and ask for ones you think you can do one at a time.
3. See if you can sit in on the status meetings

Comment: What or where is MENA? And what makes you think it is applicable, since it is not mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Mawg MENA is Middle East and Northern Africa - though i cannot fathom how/if Strader inferred that Leonidas is from there.

Comment: Guessing from a Greek sounding user name? (+1 for clarification; thanks)

Comment: @Mawg That would be a weird inference, because Greece is in Europe, not in the Middle East, nor North Africa.

Comment: Lolx. Maybe I was thinking of Alexander, the Macedonian, who founded a few cities in Egypt?

Comment: @Mawg OP mention his location in the comment that i dont see now.
Would not mention it in the answer otherwise.

For other locations, other things come in to play, i.e. North american workplace is known to be "easing" in the new hires in to the process and document review may  be a first step of the employee`s integration